# On the Variable Coefficient Laplacian

Tags: riemannian-geometry, laplacian

This the copy of the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3280442/on-the-variable-coefficient-laplacian) that I had asked in math stackexchange

I read about Laplace Operator [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Laplace_operator). As given in the link, given the metric, we can find the expression for Laplace operator. I am curious to know whether it is always possible to reduce the given variable coefficient Laplacian to the standard form by choosing the metric appropriately.

For example, given the variable coefficient Laplacian in standard Euclidean metric
\begin{equation}
  L=\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i(x)\partial_{x_i}^2
\end{equation}
where $a_i(x)>\delta>0, \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Let
\begin{equation}
  L_g=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\partial_{y_i}^2
\end{equation}
Is there a metric $g$ for which $L$ has the form $L_g$?

Comment: in general $L_g$ will also contain first derivatives, which you cannot eliminate.

Comment: This is precisely the prize question that Riemann answered, by defining the Riemann curvature tensor, and in the process inventing Riemannian geometry.